# PHPmyadmin Errors

Tags: codeigniter, phpmyadmin

I am receiving the above errors on my Phpmyadmin home page. I don't believe that i have touched anything and it was working OK before hand. I am struggling to understand the problem when looking at the documentation. I am using a codeigniter application and recently been working on sessions if that may be the cause of the issue. Any help greatly appreciated.

---

The phpMyAdmin configuration storage is not completely configured, some extended features have been deactivated. To find out why click here.

Your configuration file contains settings (root with no password) that correspond to the default MySQL privileged account. Your MySQL server is running with this default, is open to intrusion, and you really should fix this security hole by setting a password for user 'root'.

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['users'] ...    not OK [ Documentation ]
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['usergroups'] ...   not OK [ Documentation ]
Configurable menus: Disabled

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['navigationhiding'] ... not OK [ Documentation ]
Hide/show navigation items: Disabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error refer to the fact that the root password for mysql hasn't been set.  You can set it by doing the following on the command line

```
mysqladmin -u root password NEWPASSWORD
```

**It's important you fix this** because otherwise its a security flaw.  Without setting a root password it would mean that anyone could connect to your database and have root access.  You should have been prompted to set a root password when you installed MySQL

Answer (score 0):

It seems you should set a password for the root user. You can do this in MySQL with this:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('newpasswordhere');
```

If you have access to the command-line, you can also do this:

```
mysqladmin -u root password "newpasswordhere"
```

I got this information from the [MySQL Default Privileges Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/default-privileges.html)